# Promise return type error after TypeScript upgrade

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

Using `typescript` v2.3.4, the following code worked fine:

```
    getStuff() : Promise<IStuff>{

        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then( (res) => {
                let stuff: IStuff;
                if (res.json().data){
                    stuff = res.json().data;
                }
                return stuff;
            })
            .catch( (reason) => {
                this.handleError(reason);
            });
    }
```

...where `handleError` is like this:

```
handleError = (error:any) => {
    this.debug(error);
    throw error;
};
```

Now, with `typescript` v2.4.1 I get the error: `'Type 'Promise<void | IStuff>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IStuff>'. Type 'void | IStuff' is not assignable to type 'IStuff'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IStuff'.'`

I can see why that would be the case.

...but this DOES work, and it makes no sense to me that it would work when the other code does not:

```
getStuff() : Promise<IStuff>{

    return this.http.get(url, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then( (res) => {
            let stuff: IStuff;
            if (res.json().data){
                stuff = res.json().data;
            }
            return stuff;
        })
        .catch( (reason) => {
                if( reason.status) {
                    return Promise.reject(reason);
                } else {
                    this.handleError(reason);
                }
        });
}
```

...in the `else` case, it is doing exactly what the code above that generates the error is doing, and yet there's no error.

I can fix the problem by just changing `handleError` to be:

```
handleError = (error:any):Promise<any> => {
    this.debug(error);
    Promise.reject(error);
};
```

...but I'm curious what the specific change was that caused this to become an error, and why does adding the `if/else` block work correctly when it has an else path that is identical to the original code?

Comment: It looks like a return type of `void` is added if there is no return statement at all in either the `then`/`catch` blocks. As soon as you add one it will try to infer the return type on that line(s) and not implicitly add `void` even when not all code paths return a value. As to why that is I am not sure, maybe by design or maybe because tracing all possible code paths was difficult in the transpiler so an error could not be emitted or maybe it is a bug.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  I'm also kind of assuming that the fact my code was working originally was a bug, and the current behaviour is just a result of that bug being fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the TypeScript 2.4 release, TypeScript has become stricter with generics and Promise callbacks, which will cause issues with upgrades, especially those that use Promises. I've noticed this in several of my apps. You can [read about it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) in the release notes for 2.4.