# In latest TypeScript 2.4 need to cast 'as' where I didn't need to in 2.3

Tags: typescript, rxjs

this used to work just fine in TS 2.3

```
getCampaigns(): Observable<List<CampaignsModelExt>> {
        return this.store.select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns)
            .take(1)
    }
```

but with 2.4 I get an error of:

Error:(628, 9) TS2322:Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'.
  Type 'List' is not assignable to type 'List'.
    Type 'CampaignsModel' is not assignable to type 'CampaignsModelExt'.
      Property 'getCampaignPlaylistModeName' is missing in type 'CampaignsModel'.

so in order to fix it I have to cast it now: `as Observable<List<CampaignsModelExt>>;`

```
getCampaigns(): Observable<List<CampaignsModelExt>> {
        return this.store.select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns)
            .take(1) as Observable<List<CampaignsModelExt>>;
    }
```

any ideas why?

and if you are wondering about my `store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns`
its typed as `table_campaigns?: List<CampaignsModel>;`

Thanks you,

Sean

Comment: This is most likely related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793859/rxjs-subject-d-ts-error-class-subjectt-incorrectly-extends-base-class-obs

Comment: Basically, TypeScript 2.4 is more strict on generics

Comment: it's a pain, why do I have to tell it again what it is returning, I already typed it as the return and it is the same :/

Comment: They are not the same. If `getCampaigns` returned `Observable<List<CampaignsModel>>` you would not have the problem. A `CampaignsModel` is not necessarily a `CampaignsModelExt` and that is now checked in the generics and is an error.

Comment: mmm I understand, do you mind also looking into another related Q's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153925/why-is-the-new-generics-in-typescript-2-4-causing-this-to-fail

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043503/promise-return-type-error-after-typescript-upgrade/45045989#45045989), which covers roughly the same thing.

Basically, TypeScript 2.4 is far stricter when it comes to generics and Promises. You can read the release notes [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) that explain it.

Comment: tx, so I can understand this as CampaignModel is not the same as CampaignModelExt... so posted related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153925/why-is-the-new-generics-in-typescript-2-4-causing-this-to-fail