# Why is the new generics in TypeScript 2.4 causing this to fail?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, immutable.js

So I understand that with TS 2.4 we get trickter generic checks.
But what I don't understand is why now I get with this:

```
getChannelBlockModels(i_campaign_timeline_chanel_id): Observable<List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>> {
        return this.store.select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaign_timeline_chanel_players)
            .map((campaignTimelineChanelPlayersModels: List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>) => {
                return campaignTimelineChanelPlayersModels.filter(campaignTimelineChanelsModel => {
                    return campaignTimelineChanelsModel.getCampaignTimelineChanelId() == i_campaign_timeline_chanel_id;
                })
            }).take(1);
    }
```

this error:

```
Error:(806, 9) TS2322:Type 'Observable<Iterable<number, CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>>'.
  Type 'Iterable<number, CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>' is not assignable to type 'List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>'.
    Property 'set' is missing in type 'Iterable<number, CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>'.
```

as I am returning `Observable<List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>>` so why isn't TS happy?

Comment: What is `List` and what is the signature of its `filter` method?

Comment: List is Immutable.js List class List<T> extends Collection.Indexed<T>

Comment: Whatever it is, its `filter` method does not return a `List` and that is the source of the error. The second line of the error states the problem. You return the `filter` result from `map`, so that becomes the type for the observable's value and it does not match - and is not compatible with - your function signature's return type.

Comment: this is the thing, the line of   .map((campaignTimelineChanelPlayersModels: List<CampaignTimelineChanelPlayersModel>) => { ... receives a list and all that filter does it reduce the list to matching values which is also... well a shorter list, and it works in runtime, so I am still not sure why its not liking it :(

Comment: It's just the typings that are complaining - and with good reason. Note that the error mentions a `set` property. The typings that you have in place assert that `set` exists on the observable's value, but it does not - hence the error. If you were to use/call `set` you *would* see a runtime error effected.

Comment: thanks for the replies, and yes I see that it "thinks" set should exist, but I would think it should infer that the return type should be the same as the given argument to filter which is a List.

Comment: There is no inference involved regarding the return type of `filter`; it sounds like the `filter` method of `List` does not return `List` and that's that. The `map` result will be the type returned by `filter`. TypeScript's behaviour is correct and reasonable.